# First finish() in success handler works fine, second finish() doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish

I've been trying to wrap my head around the following issue for the last 6 hours of so, but I cannot figure it out. I believe it should be an easy issue to fix, but somehow it's not.

I use an [Async HTTP library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) which has several completion handlers, one of which is `onSuccess()`. The code of my success handler looks like the following:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String json) {
    // {"statusId":12,"statusText":"Ongeldige logincode","result":[],"duration":"0.320","update":[]}
    // {"statusId":1,"statusText":"OK","result":{"id":"38790","planHash":"0FYzJAodmQzUnZkSEJzWVc1dWFXNW5KbXhzYm5WdFBUTTROemt3","warnCBR":"NO","data":{"name":"Jeroen Dielemans","mail":"j.dielemans@live.nl","address":"Oude Antwerpse Postbaan 6","zip":"4741TK","city":"Hoeven","phone":"0165-502684","mobile":"06-15617390"}},"duration":"1.538","update":[]}
    json = "{\"statusId\":1,\"statusText\":\"OK\",\"result\":[],\"duration\":\"3.910\",\"update\":{\"id\":22,\"title\":\"Update!\",\"text\":\"Hee er is een nieuwe versie ;)\",\"button\":\"Open\",\"link\":\"market:\\/\\/details?id=com.dga.blom>\"}}";

    Integer statusId = 1; // 1 == success
    String statusText = null;
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject update = null;

    try {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json)
                .nextValue();
        statusId = object.getInt("statusId");
        statusText = object.getString("statusText");
        result = object.optJSONObject("result");
        update = object.optJSONObject("update");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (statusId != 1) {
        showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.failed), statusText);
    } else {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

        if (result != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_USER,
                    result.toString());
            editor.commit();

            Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(
                    Constants.INTENT_REFRESH_ACTION);
            sendBroadcast(refreshIntent);
        } 

        if (update == null) {
            finish(); /* ALWAYS closes activity */
        } else {
            int updateId = update.optInt("id", -1);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int lastId = prefs.getInt(
                    Constants.LAST_UPDATE_MESSAGE_ID, -1);

            if (updateId > lastId) {
                showUpdateDialog(update);
            } else {
                finish(); /* NEVER closes activity */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the relevant piece of code is near the end.

When there's no value for `update` I will just close the activity by calling `finish()`. This always works fine.

If a value for `update` exists, I'll check if the update identifier is never then the last stored value. If the update identifier is indeed newer, I'll show a dialog. If the update identifier is not newer I try to close the activity by calling `finish()` and continue with the app. This second `finish()` call never works.

I should note that my emulator seems to have a small hiccup on this second `finish()` call, yet LogCat doesn't mention any errors, warnings or the like.

Why won't the second `finish()` close my activity?

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting LAST_UPDATE_MESSAGE_ID propely to SharedPrefs?

Comment: I don't think there's any issues there. In the debugger I do notice the second `finish()` is being called (using breakpoints) when I have an `update` object and the updateId is equal or smaller as the lastId.

Comment: So your problem is that it is being called but it doesn't close activity, right?

Comment: Indeed. I do notice a small "hiccup", but the activity won't ever close on the second `finish()` call.

Comment: Have you tried executing finish with activity Context? I don't know where onSuccess method is located. If it's seperate class it might not see the activity? Just throwing an idea.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs : first make sure control is going inside else block and then try to close Activity as `Your_Current_Activity.this.finish()`

Comment: I'm 100% sure the else block is being reached. Using `LoginActivity.this.finish()` makes no difference :( @fliespl I tried your suggestion by adding a Activity variable to the AsyncHttpConnection and calling finish on this Activity variable, but this made no difference either.

Comment: The "hiccup" I mentioned seems to be caused by the garbage collector by the way. The `finish()` method does seem to trigger the GC somehow. Perhaps this is somehow related to my issue?

Comment: Ok, still it seems like it doesn't go to this other finish ;) Please try Toast instead of finish and let us know of the output (or not)

Comment: I've added a method `showToast()` in the else path. The toast created by the method does show up when I test.

Answer (score 0):

In what condition is update not null?  Is there possibly a second instance of the same activity below your currently running activity, so the top activity is in fact finishing, but it doesn't look like it because the activity it is returning to has the same layout?